# Binary Search in Java does not terminate

Tags: java, binary-search

I have been trying to implement `binary search` in Java, the program does not increment `left` after it reaches `10`. I could easily get the code for the same on the internet, but I want to figure out why my code is not working.

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] li = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
        30 };
    int target = 19;
    int left = 0, right = li.length;
    while (left < right) {
      int mid = (right - left) / 2;
      if (li[mid] == target) {
        System.out.println(mid);
        break;
      }
      else if (li[mid] < target) {
        System.out.println("li[mid] < target");
        left = mid + 1;
        System.out.println(left);
      }

      if (li[mid] > target) {
        System.out.println("li[mid] > target");
        right = mid - 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The output**

```
li[mid] < target
10
li[mid] < target
10
li[mid] < target
10
li[mid] < target
10
li[mid] < target
10
```

Comment: must be `else if (li[mid] > target)`. In your case you modify left and right simultaneously so mid is not changing

Comment: This is what a debugger is for.  Have you stepped through this code yourself?  It should be easy to debug this if you just follow the logic in a debugger.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, your next step is to learn.  I see one obvious problem.  This line `int mid = (right - left) / 2;` isn't doing what you expect.  You want something more like: `int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;`. `(right - left)` by itself is a distance, not an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the concept of Binary search correct, but there are some minor issues. First, `right` should be set to `li.length-1`. Then, when you assign `mid`, you need to add `left` as well. The code will now be:

```java
    // ...
    int target = 19;
    int left = 0, right = li.length-1; // 1. fix value of right
    while (left < right) {
      int mid = left + (right - left) / 2; // 2. added left to mid
      if (li[mid] == target) {
        // ...
```

1. The array is zero indexed, and `length` returns the number of elements in the array. The elements themselves, go from `0` to `length-1`. So, `right` is adjusted to contain the index of the final element. You can test this out by removing the `-1` and setting `target` to the last element `30`. This will cause an error.
2. `mid` is supposed to store the index of the middle element of the currently searched section of the array. The current section starts at `left` and ends at `right`. So, to find the middle element, we use `lower bound + (upper bound - lower bound) / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple major errors.

Your underlying problem is that you aren't debugging your code; you can't run to SO or somebody else everytime your code doesn't immediately work - trust me, code (written by anybody, even wintered veterans) has far too many bugs to make that a feasible plan :)

Print not just `left`. Print more stuff, until you have a good grasp on what the code is actually doing. Or, better, use a debugger and step through. First figure out in your head what is supposed to occur, then check if it actually occurs.

Had you done that, you'd have immediately realized that `(right - left) / 2` does **not** calculate an average. You wanted `(right + left) /2`.

Comment: This seems like kinda half an answer to me.

Comment: I do get your point, maybe I spent a lot of time looking at the same problem, and I just got too frustrated, also while looking at the problem, I found an article that suggests using `left + (right-left)/2` since `(right+left)/2` can cause overflows.

Comment: `(right - left) / 2` calculates something completely different. @CryptoFool it's a homework question, just 'here, this is the code you are looking for' is not an appropriate answer, so they tend to get a little 'oh hey consider this and then maybe look at that line'.

Answer (score 1):

Your code just needs a few revisions to function:

```
int left = 0, right = li.length - 1;
```

Remember that arrays use zero base indexing, so the rightmost index is the length minus one.

```
while (left < right)
```

Binary search will eventually reach a one element range where left == right.

```
int mid = (right - left) / 2;
```

You need to add the left index to this result to account for a non-zero left index. Your code results in this:
left = 0, right = 10 -> mid = 5
left = 5, right = 10 -> mid = 2 ** SHOULD BE 7 **

You should also clean up your branch statements as shown below.

```
int left = 0, right = li.length - 1;
while (left <= right) {
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
    if (target < li[mid]) {
        System.out.println("target < li[mid]");
        right = mid - 1;
        System.out.println(right);
    }
    else if (target > li[mid]) {
        System.out.println("target < li[mid]");
        left = mid + 1;
        System.out.println(left);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(mid);
        break;
    }
}
```

I would recommend that you step through this algorithm in a debugger to understand why it's failing and (once it's fixed) how it works.

Comment: This does not work for targets less than the first value in the list.

Comment: @CryptoFool You're right, I made a mistake when rewriting the branches. It's been fixed.